# Entities: Adding a Navigation Property between a View and Table

Tags: linq-to-entities, navigation, properties, entity

As you can seen in the diagram below there is a one-to-many relationship between the ProjectTask and Dependency table.

[image: Database Diagram]

Entities tries to map every field in the View to fields in the Dependency table, which wouldn't work.

Any suggestions on how I can add the navigation property?

Thanks,
Abe

---

Here's the link to the Mapping diagram:

[Mapping Diagram](http://i805.photobucket.com/albums/yy339/abepark/tableAssoc.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, when you add a database view to your model, Entity Framework will assume every single column is part of the primary key. It does the same thing if you add a table without a primary key defined.

The solution is to manually edit the edmx file with an XML editor and define the primary key yourself. Find the <EntityType> tag for your view (<EntityType Name="MyView">), then there will be a <Key> element. Remove any non-key columns from that element.

Comment: FWIW, you no longer have to edit the EDMX to change the Model's PK. Simply look at the properties for the columns on the model under `Entity Types` (not under `Tables/Views`), and change the `EntityKey` property to false.