# Create one-way association/mapping in Entity Data Model?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net-entity-data-model, entitydatasource

Okay, as usual, I'm brand new to this... been researching and trial/erroring (yes that's a verb) for a couple hours with no luck.  I have two tables.  **Application** and **ApplicationType**.  **ApplicationType** lists all the possible types.  Let's use colors for simplicity.  Red, Green, Blue, etc.  So I have a column called *Type_ID* that would contain 1 for red, 2 for green, etc.  Back to the **Application** table/entity, I have a column called *Type_ID* that corresponds. This is what I want to map.  However, whenever I try, I continually get the error:

> "Must specify mapping for all key
>   properties (Application_ID) of End
>   Application in Relationship
>   ApplicationTypeApplication"

*Application_ID* is the Entity Key for **Application**, obviously, but there is NO corresponding column in **ApplicationType**.  Whenever I go to the table mapping details it always shows EVERY key.  So, this is probably simply a major misunderstanding on my part, but any help would be much appreciated.  I normally just use SQL queries but my coworker talked me into trying LINQ so her I am.

Comment: The EF will infer all of this if you have a proper FK in your DB. Do you?

Comment: lol, funny story...  I'm using "views" designed by someone else (a company DBA).

:(

Comment: OK, that's your problem, then. Since views don't have a proper PK, the EF defaults to treating all columns in the view as parts of a composite PK. You need to [edit the mapping to correct the Key definition for the view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545131/entities-adding-a-navigation-property-between-a-view-and-table), since it can't be inferred from metadata.

Comment: Craig if you post that as an answer I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using a view and views don't have a proper PK, the EF defaults to treating all columns in the view as parts of a composite PK. You need to [edit the mapping to correct the Key definition for the view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545131/entities-adding-a-navigation-property-between-a-view-and-table), since it can't be inferred from metadata.