# Custom function to determine "Navigation" property in either EF4 or straight T-SQL

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework

[Apologies for the long winded explanation]

I have inherited an aold application with a SQL database from an (very!) old product and I need to do some reporting against the DB directly.  Not entirely sure WHY but this is the structure I have uncovered:

I have a Groups table, and a Reports table.

Groups has a `type` column, 'R' or 'G', an integer `numElements` and an `image` column called `elements`

Type 'R' means the Group contains Reports, 'G' means it contains more Groups.

```
type = 'G'
elements = 0x2C002600
numelements = 2
result = take chunks of 4 characters, 
         reverse the last and first two character pairs to get 002C and 0026
convert hex to int to get 44 and 38
```

44 and 38 are two Group ID's  - I can verify this from within the application itself.

The same applies for type 'R' where the ID's resulting are Reports

Is there any way to Map this behaviour in EF4 **OR** T-SQL so that I can start to do some sensible queries?
e.g.

```
If type = G and numElements = 3
    split the hex string into 3 chunks of 4 characters, 
    reverse character pairs, 
    convert to int, 
    map to Groups

If type = R and numElements = 11
    split the hex string into 11 chunks of 4 characters, 
    reverse character pairs, 
    convert to int, 
    map to Reports
```

There are thousands of reports and hundreds of groups, so although within the application I can see the groupings, to map them manually would take forever.  There is no tree view, so I have to open a group to see what it contains, then open sub-groups (if present) etc. etc.

I know I can code this manually and go through line-by-line abnd extract, split, reverse, convert...but wondered if there was a way I could get T-SQL or EF to do this for me?

---

**EDIT:**

Please note, the numElements is variable, since a Group can contain 1:Many Groups OR 1:Many Reports (but not a mixture of them).  Therefore the hex string is always:
"0x" + "4 x numElements" characters long

This means that the "hex to int" function needs to be able to return an array or similar, so that 1 Group can be linked to Many Groups/Reports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that will help you with both is to create a scalar function which does that split, reverse and convert.

I would create three functions:

```
dbo.fnSplitHex(varchar hex, int chunks)  -- the actual split etc

dbo.fnSplitGHex(varchar hex) return dbo.fnSplitHex(hex, 3) -- pass 3 for chunks
dbo.fnSplitRHex(varchar hex) return dbo.fnSplitHex(hex, 11) -- pass 11 for chunks
```

Unfortunately you can't create a Navigation Property based on this only. However you can create a view:

```
  select *, dbo.fnSplitHex(..) from table1
```

With LINQ 2 SQL I can create a Navigation Property between the view and another table, as long as I define a PrimaryKey for the view, in the model. <del>Not sure with EF...</del> [EF also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545131/entities-adding-a-navigation-property-between-a-view-and-table)

**Response On Question Edit**

Since the convert function depends on **numElements**, an external input and not like the **hex** param which is a column in the main table and can be read from there, you have no option in creating a NavigationProperty between the main table and Groups or Reports.

Unfortunately your problems don't stop here. This being a table function (returns a table with a single column of type int), EF can't use it as a "composable" function, like in the following example:

```
  from c in Groups
  from sg in fnGetIntsFromHex('G', 3, c.hex) into groups from sg in groups.DefaultIfEmpty()
  join g in Groups on sg.GroupId equals g.GroupId
  select g
```

This would have to generate a SQL statement with a CROSS APPLY operator, but now it can't do it (EF 2011 June CTE can, but is CTE).

What is left? I think going back to stored procedure is not such a bad thing. Other options depends on your numElements set. If this set is limited in a reasonable way, you still can create views like:

```
create view dbo.vwSubgropus3
as
begin

select f.GroupId, f.Value = SubGroupId
from group g
where g.Type = 'G'
cross apply fnGetIntsFromHex(g.Hex, 3) f


create view dbo.vwSubgropus11
as
begin

select f.GroupId, f.Value as SubGroupId
from group g
where g.Type = 'G'
cross apply fnGetIntsFromHex(g.Hex, 11) f


create view dbo.vwReports3
as
begin

select f.GroupId, f.Value as ReportId
from group g
where g.Type = 'R'
cross apply fnGetIntsFromHex(g.Hex, 3) f
```

Comment: can this return an array/list of ints? (not a SQL expert!)

Comment: You can create a table function, but you can't use it with EF now. They will support table functions when .Net 4.5 is shipped. So use that table function in a view and try to map it in the model.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1545131/entities-adding-a-navigation-property-between-a-view-and-table Here how to add a Navigation Property between a table and a view

Comment: Please see my edit to original question...realised it wasn't clear.

Comment: Of you can get rid of numElements, so you can extract the ints from the hex without this.